# Encounter problems when installing openvino development tools on Windows

Tags: deep-learning, deployment, yolov5, openvino

Following the official docs [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_install_dev_tools.html#install-dev-tools), error happened! The version of openvino tool is 22.3.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\Scripts\mo.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\mo\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .convert import convert_model, InputCutInfo, LayoutMap
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\mo\convert.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openvino.tools.mo.convert_impl import _convert
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\mo\convert_impl.py", line 21, in <module>
    from openvino.tools.mo.back.SpecialNodesFinalization import RemoveConstOps, CreateConstNodesReplacement, NormalizeTI
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\mo\back\SpecialNodesFinalization.py", line 13, in <module>
    from openvino.tools.mo.ops.const import Const
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\mo\ops\const.py", line 7, in <module>
    from openvino.tools.mo.middle.passes.convert_data_type import data_type_str_to_np, np_data_type_to_destination_type, \
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\mo\middle\passes\convert_data_type.py", line 8, in <module>
    from openvino.tools.mo.front.extractor import get_new_placeholder_name
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\mo\front\extractor.py", line 11, in <module>
    from openvino.runtime import PartialShape, Dimension
  File "D:\conda_envs\yolov5_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\runtime\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from openvino._pyopenvino import get_version
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pyopenvino: 找不到指定的模块。
```

I search on the Internet, but nothing works.

Comment: The error message is in an Asian script, you would have to translate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

Option 1:
Open the Command Prompt, and run the setupvars.bat batch file to temporarily set OpenVINO™ environment variables:

```
<INSTALL_DIR>\setupvars.bat
```

Option 2:
Add OpenVINO™ installation path into the environment variable:

```
%PATH%=C:/USERS/USER/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python38/site-packages/openvino/libs
```